# jquery:binding a hover event with ajax loaded content

Tags: jquery, hover

I'm using jQuery to try and bind some newly loaded `<li>` elements with `.hover()` and I'm kind of stuck. At the moment I'm reloading the content in a `<ul>` with ajax and there's a hover event with `.hover();` on the `<li>`. The hover event works perfectly on the non-ajax-loaded content of course.

I know I can use `mouseover`/`mouseout` to bind the event with `.live();` which is a good solution if it weren't for `mouseover`/`mouseout` bad habit to break the event if you hover a child element of the current element the mouseover is bound to. So the reason I'm using `.hover();` is because I can freely hover the children of my hover-bound element without the event being cancelled.

`bind();` doesn't seem to work at all either, so my question is.. Is there any use in trying to get ajax loaded `<li>` events bound and keep the hover effect as a `hover();`, or should I just roll over and use `mouseover`/`mouseout` with `live();` and try and solve the hover children problem some other how?

#### Success Message:

```
success: function(data){ 
           $('ul#list').bind().append("<li>test test</li>");
         }
```

Comment: can you show how you are rebinding in the ajax success event?

Answer (score 8):

bind works like [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/bind).
e.g

```
$('#list').bind('mouseover', function(){})
```

However I think what you need to do is just call the same function that you use to bind the event when the document first loads. If this is inside a document ready block then extract it into a function and just call the same function in doc ready and in the ajax success event.

e.g

```
$(document).ready( function(){

   bindHover( $('#list>li') )

   $.ajax({ success: function(data){
                         bindHover( data.find('li') );
                     },
            url: bla
   });

})

function bindHover($liList){
  $liList.hover( fn, fn )
}
```

Comment: Ok, so what do I put in the function(){  });, I only want my newly ajax added elements to respond to the hover() event.

Comment: ok changed the above to show how you only pass the new li elements to the bindHover function therefore the  existing li elements wont get duplicate event handlers